# DataGridView sort causes cell to be selected even if selection was cleared before the sort

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

This question generally applies to the standard DataGridView. For some reason it will always select a cell after sort, even if there is no cell selected (selection was cleared) at the moment the user clicks on the column header to sort the DataGridView. To explain why I really don't want this, I need to provide a little more background about my project.

I need to extend the functionality of the DataGridView, while keeping databinding intact. Firstly, I need to organize the data into expandable/collapsible groups. Later, other functionality already written specifically for the DataGridView (by others) will be added. This means I do not have the freedom to use a third-party grid component that isn't built around the DataGridView.

Therefore I've decided to use the DataGridViewGrouper component written by HotDog (Robert Verpalen), see [this link](http://blogs.vbcity.com/hotdog/archive/2008/12/19/9225.aspx) for his code. In this component collapsed rows are hidden by setting their visible property to false.

In principal it works, until I try sorting the data after having selected one of the group rows. In that case it throws an error: ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I thought I'd take a shortcut to solve this problem and added:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
if (dataGridViewGrouper1.CurrentRowIsGroupRow)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

There is no reason why users would have to be able to select one of the group rows, and clearing their selection gets rid of the error I got when I tried to sort. 
However, after sorting, there is always a cell that gets selected; even if the selection was cleared before the sort.

I've added a CellMouseDown event to keep track of which cell was last selected before sorting, so that after the sort I can select the same cell again (and not the cell that happens to sit at the same row index).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 0) { return;  }
        selected = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I return from this method if there are no selected cells (there is after all nothing to be remembered). The fact that this return does indeed occur if a sort is attempted after a group row was last selected, means my attempt to clear that selection was successful.

However, after the sort a cell is still selected in this case. This is a seemingly random chosen cell somewhere in the group. I suspect it is somehow related to the position of the cell that was selected before the selection was cleared. This leads to rather annoying behavior, like the screen jumping to this selected cell's position (a few hundred lines away) or an invisible row in a collapsed group becoming visible as it is selected.

I can't find out during which event the cell is selected. I've tried to keep track of which group row was selected before the sort, so that I can later select something else and if necessary make all the rows in that group invisible again, but I didn't manage. I also feel this isn't the right way to fix this problem.

Similarly, working with loops to select the closest by visible data cell before going into the sort action rather than clearing the selection, doesn't seem like a great solution. Especially because I would still have a problem when all groups are collapsed (there are no visible data rows).

What I really want (I think) is to stop a cell from being selected after a sort, if there wasn't one selected before the sort. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Although this is an old post, I was wondering if you're still using the component. The code posted on the blog was an old primary version and has had many updates since (for clarity, my vbcity name was hotdog). Since the old vbcity blog is down I got word that someone was looking for the code and am thinking of uploading a newer version to codeproject. (although the current version has also been in stasis for some time now)

Comment: We are still using the component, in a somewhat tweaked form. It would definitely be interesting to take a look at a newer version of the code.

Comment: The component and code is now available here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/995958/DataGridViewGrouper

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call Sort(), DataBindingCompleted event also rises (very annoying) and even if your selection in DataGridView was cleared, BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource].Position doesn't change, and your selection is automatically set to the current position in your data source after sorting (I think).

To remedy this, either reset your position in data before sorting:

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
                {
                    BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource].Position = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

or remove selection after sorting (beware that that doesn't changes Position either!)

```
void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
i have found some ugly hack, although it rerquires overriding DataGridView protected functionality. Also, I didn't fully test it so it may cause some strange behaviour later (no warranties). But it works in basic settings. First, call **dataGridView1.ClearSelection();** on CellClick, if the column header was clicked. Then:

```
public class DGV:DataGridView
{
        bool isSorted = false;

        public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            isSorted = true;
            base.Sort(dataGridViewColumn, direction);
        }
        protected override void OnSorted(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSorted(e);
            isSorted = false;

        }

protected override void SetSelectedCellCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool selected)
        {
            // here is where cell gets selected so just ignore it when sorting
            if (isSorted)
            {
                return;
            }

            base.SetSelectedCellCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, selected);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried both, but neither way solves the fact that after sorting when all groups are collapsed at some point a row gets selected, and this row becomes visible. I look some more into this DataBindingCompleted event though! Thanks for pointing its existence out to me!

Comment: Thanks again. This SetSelectedCellCore bit sounds really promising! I copied your class into my namespace, but when debugging I never reach the breakpoints I have set inside. I'm going to do some research concerning using override to find out if I placed the code wrong. I see that override is also being used on ApplySort in the DataGridViewGrouper component. Maybe I'm trying to override things that have already been 'overrode'... If you have anymore thoughts on this, let me know.

Comment: I ended up cheating my way out of this. The datagridviewgrouper turned out to have a grid_sorted event. I now clear the selection in this event and then just recollapse all groups that are supposed to be collapsed. Thanks for helping me understand the DataGridView component a lot better!

Comment: This worked for me but in my case I had to override `SetSelectedRowCore` instead of `SetSelectedCellCore`. There is also a `SetSelectedColumnCore` and a `SetCurrentCellAddressCore` which might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `CurrentCell` `Selected` property to `False` like:

```
dataGridViewName.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
```

Comment: I have now (in the dataGridView1_CellMouseClick event)... but it didn't work. I get the exact same behavior as before. Thanks for trying to help though!